# Python multiple boxplots automatic label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to automatically set labels for multiple boxplots? I know it can probably be done with custom annotations or ticklabels, but is it also possible automatically?

Naively one would expect something like the following, but plt.boxplot doesn't support labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Fake data
data = (np.random.random(50), np.random.random(50))
labels = ('random set 1', 'random set 2')

plt.boxplot(data, labels=labels)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the shortest and cleanest is probably along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Fake data
data = (np.random.random(50), np.random.random(50))
labels = ('random set 1', 'random set 2')

plt.boxplot(data)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(labels))+1,labels)
plt.show()
```

But I'm still open to other (automatic) suggestions.